# Comparing differences two files in Unix to produce bool

Tags: shell, diff

say I have two files..
file1 & file2, both have different names but the same content inside

I tried comparing them through

```
[[ file1 = file2 ]]
```

& using

```
diff file1 file2
[[ echo $? ]]
```

however both return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`cmp`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/cmp.html):

```sh
if cmp -s file1 file2; then
    echo "They're the same."
else
    echo "They're different"
fi
```